# Add fake tick to x-axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I suppose the title says it all. I have a dataset without any data for day 0, but for illustration purposes I would like to include day 0 on a discrete x-axis, is this possible?
Example code below, the facetting is necessary for my original data.

```
tmp=expand.grid(Mig=c("A","B"),
                Measure=c("Rel", "Abs"),
                Mean=rnorm(1,2,3),
                Day=factor(c(-14:-1,1:14), levels=c(-14:-1, 1:14)))
tmp$Group=with(tmp, paste(Mig, Measure))
ggplot(tmp, aes(x=Day, y=Mean, group=Group))+
    facet_grid(Mig~Measure)+
    geom_line()+
    scale_x_discrete(breaks=seq(-14,14,2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert `Day` to integer or numeric it seems to work.

```
tmp$Day <- as.integer(as.character(tmp$Day))

ggplot(tmp, aes(x=Day, y=Mean, group=Group))+
  facet_grid(Mig~Measure)+
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(-14,14,2))
```

[image: Fixing labels]

**EDIT:** Fixed breaks.

Comment: Thank you! To remove the empty area to the left I changed the last line to: scale_x_discrete(limits=seq(-14,14,2))

Comment: Sorry I should have fixed that in my answer first time around. See the edit. `scale_x_discrete()` should be `scale_x_continuous()`.